# Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException'

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm having an issue where my android instrumentation tests are not discovered. instead I get the following:

```
Started running tests
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 
'kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Empty test suite.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, It was because I had a property with the lateinit annotation that was not injected